# Cannot invoke equalsIgnoreCase() on the primitive type boolean

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, bukkit

I'm creating a plugin for bukkit servers, an antiswear one, but i'm trying to not make it case sensitive, how can i do this? code:

```
package me.Lorenzo.AntiSwear;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.player.AsyncPlayerChatEvent;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class Main extends JavaPlugin implements Listener {

    @EventHandler
    public void onPlayerChat(AsyncPlayerChatEvent e) {
            for(String word : e.getMessage().split(" ")){
                    if(getConfig().getStringList("bannedwords").contains(word)){
                                    e.setCancelled(true);
                                    e.getPlayer().sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "Please don't use that sort of language!");
                    }
            }
    }





    public void onEnable() {
            getConfig().options().copyDefaults(true);
            saveConfig();
            Bukkit.getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);
    }

}
```

Comment: You probably should replace the Javascript tag with Java

Answer (score 0):

1. In `onEnable`, make sure all `bannedwords` are lowercase.
2. In `onPlayerChat`, use `e.getMessage().toLowerCase().split(" ")` instead of `e.getMessage().split(" ")`

Answer (score 0):

How about adding toLowerCase():

```
if(getConfig().getStringList("bannedwords").contains(word.toLowerCase())){
```

Comment: just's answer is more efficient